# Python 3 tkinter image displayed in wrong column

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I want my label to be displayed **in the same column** as the picture. Both of them are generated with a click. I place them in the same column of the grid, but the image is displayed in the neighbour column. What's the reason and how to correct it?

Here's my simplified code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, padding='20')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        self.create_button()

    def create_button(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self,
                                 text="Click",
                                 width=12,
                                 command=lambda: self.display_name_and_picture()
                                 ).grid(column=2, columnspan=2, row=1, sticky=NW)

    def display_name_and_picture(self):
        random_label = ttk.Label(self, font=(None, 16), text='random random')
        random_label.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=N)

        random_image = PhotoImage(file='random.gif')
        label = Label(image=random_image)
        label.image = random_image
        label.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky=NW)

root = Tk()
root.title("Random something...")
root.geometry("600x300")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In your `create_button`  method change `command` to 

`command=self.display_name_and_picture`

Comment: `self.button = ttk.Button(...).grid(...)` sets self.Button to None.  If you do not need `self.button`, eliminate the assignment.  If you do, split the statement into `self.button = ttk.Button(...)` and `self.button.grid(...)`.

Comment: The second label lacks the `ttk` prefix. The `label.image` attribute assignment seems useless.

Comment: The label.image seems to be an undocumented (that I know of) necessity.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, Without the assignment `label.image = random_image` the picture is not displayed at all. From http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm: _Note: When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g. when you return from a function which stored an image in a local variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a Tkinter widget.
To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this line

```
label = Label(image=random_image)
```

You create `label` without specifying its parent, so its parent defaults to `root`. But `random_label` has `app` as its parent, and `app` in turn has `root` as its parent. So `label` is gridded side by side with `app` --- inside `root` --- and not inside `app` as you wished. Just change the above line to

```
label = Label(self, image=random_image)
```

and you should be fine.

(Well, not totally fine. You should also fix the things people pointed out in comments.)

Comment: Adding the missing `self` fixes the major problem (at least with other adjustments I made).

Answer (score -1):

I monkeyed around with this for a while and produced something that does what you are asking.  I would love to have somebody explain why this works.  The columns look goofy.

Check it out:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, padding='20')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        self.create_button()

    def create_button(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self,
                                 text="Click",
                                 width=12,
                                 command=self.display_name_and_picture
                                 )
        self.button.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=0, sticky=NW)

    def display_name_and_picture(self):
        random_label = ttk.Label(self, font=(None, 16), text='random random')
        random_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
        random_image = PhotoImage(file='random.gif')
        label = Label(image=random_image)
        label.image = random_image
        label.grid(row=1, column=0)


root = Tk()
root.title("Random something...")
root.geometry("600x300")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You get this to work because, while `label` is still outside of `app`, you grid `app` at column 0, row 0 in `root` and grid `label` at column 0, row 1 in `root` (my answer explains why this is so). So yes `label` is below `app`.